# Running command after publishing files

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild, clickonce, publish

I am trying to run a command after publishing.

```
<Target Name="AfterPublish" AfterTargets="MSDeployPublish">
  <Exec Command="echo @@@@@ AfterPublish @@@@@ " />
</Target>
```

But as you see below, it copies the published output after calling this target.

```
------ Publish started: Project: ClickOnceTest, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>  @@@@@ AfterPublish @@@@@ 
Connecting to 'C:\temp\Debug\'...
Publishing files...
Publish success.
```

How do I get it to happen after the "Publishing files" step is finished?

Comment: This is my project file, I just want to execute a program AFTER it copys the files to the publish location. This was the only change I made to the .csproj file.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any lingering "DependsOnTargets"?

http://freetodev.wordpress.com/2009/06/24/msbuild-4-0-beforetargets-and-aftertargets/

There are some "rules of execution".......when that happens.

I don't think you've given enough of your msbuild contents.

Comment: Yeah, "after" targets don't exactly fire after.

Comment: Did you get it resolved? (I'm curious as to what your issue was........being the developer who gets stuck with msbuild stuff most of the time for our builds)